# How do I check for \n when using java scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a scanner so that every time \n is detected, it will scan the line after that until a new \n shows up. I first tried something like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String input = "first line \nsecond line \nthird line";
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
        
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String stuff = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(stuff);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Which works, and the output is

```
first line 
second line 
third line
```

However, when I try doing the same thing with Scanner(System.in) it doesn't work the same way even with same input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter things");
        
        Scanner cmd = new Scanner(System.in); //input: "first \n second \n third"
        
        String input = cmd.nextLine();
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
        
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String stuff = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(stuff);
        }
        cmd.close();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
first \n second \n third
```

## What should I change, so that every \n will print a new line?

EDIT:
If the input was

```
first
second
third
```

and entered into the prompt at once, would scanner.nextLine() be enough to suffice?

Comment: If by `//input: "first \n second \n third"` you mean that you are actually typing in console `first \n second \n third` then your console treats `\n` as *two* separate characters: ``\`` and `n` NOT as line separator. But what are you trying to do here? If you are trying to provide 3 lines then do it like `line1` [press enter] `line2` [press enter] `line3` [press enter] (now you need to decide what should stop your loop, should it stop after N lines, or after some specific text provided by user like "end" "bye").

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, I'm trying to enter everything in one go. I didn't know that `\n` are treated as two characters, thanks for informing me! So how would I split `first line \nsecond line \nthird line` if I'm entering them all at once? I understand how to enter commands line by line but that's not what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Don't enter it that way. What if your text actually will contain `\n` which *should* represent two characters like `my file is at c:\my\new\folder`? If you want to pass large chunk of data to application then maybe store it in file and then pass location of that file as argument?

Comment: @Pshemo I understand what you're saying, but the choice really isn't up to me :( I'm writing it for an assignment, and our professor said the input format will be lines separated by newline/return variables.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "variables" in "input format will be lines separated by newline/return *variables*". Anyway if input will be provided with actual line-separators then `nextLine()` should be able to handle it properly.

Comment: Scanners will normally filter out the \n, using it to define what a line is. So, the only evidence of a \n you will see is as the end of a line. Blank lines will be indicated by an empty string from Scanner#nextLine().

Comment: @Pshemo By that I meant our professor will copy/paste a whole block of commands, something like `first \n second \n third \n fourth \n etc..` and expect our code to process each one individually. I've already got everything else working, I'm just looking for a way for the scanner to scan the next line whenever `\n` shows up. So it can handle a whole block of commands rather than expecting another user input after only processing `first`

Comment: @NomadMaker I'm not exactly sure what you meant by that. Are you saying that a regular `string input = scanner.nextLine();` will automatically go to the next line? I tried doing that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "our professor will copy/paste a whole block of commands, something like `first \n second \n third \n fourth \n`" I really doubt that your professor will actually place `\n` in text which will be copied. I would rather assume that he will copy two lines which are actyally separated by proper line separators making that line separator part of data (so `nextLine()` should handle it correctly). BUT if it would really contain `\n` (which is horrible idea if text can also contain ``\`` as valid character like part of file-path) then you can split lines like `String[] lines = data.split("\\\\n");`

Comment: Anyway providing data in proper form is responsibility of user (here professor) who will need to write it with proper line separators (so no `\n` inside text). For now I would probably consult him about it (or at least ask few other students how they interpret that part of the assignment).

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Please enter things");
    Scanner cmd = new Scanner(System.in); //input: "first \n second \n third"
    
    while(cmd.hasNext()) {
        String word = cmd.next();
        if(word.equals("\\n")) {
            System.out.println();
        }else {
            System.out.print(word);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: so this was probably very confusing to a newer programmer because of 2 things, first of all \n represents 2 characters and not 1 which makes looking for it difficult. And second, even I forgot for a second that `string==" " `is not valid and will return false no matter what is in the " ". Make sure you brush up on your String methods, nice job tho!

Comment: thank for the help! It works! I'll definitely spend some time to play around with it and understand it myself. Good job mate

Comment: ya, one thing you might improve is that if there are more than one word per line it will not put a space between the words, the way you could fix that is in the else statement put `System.out.print(word+" ");`

Comment: Note that `next()` will return *single* token, so if we use input like `a b c \n second` then with `System.out.print(word);` `a` `b` `c` will end up as `abc`.

Comment: @Luke @Pshemo I see, what if each line is separated by "enter" instead of "\n"? If the input is `first (enter) second (enter) third`? Hard to type it in the comments, I'll add it to the post. Would it be easier?

Comment: @CaoTheNoob If by `(enter)` you mean series of characters `(` `e` `n` `t` `e` `r` `)` then it doesn't change anything. We just now need to specially handle it instead of ``\`` `n`.

Comment: @Pshemo no that's not what I meant, it's hard describing it for me. I added an edit to the main post. I'm dumb sorry :'(

Comment: @CaoTheNoob If data will be provided as `first (enter) second (enter) third (enter)` where (enter) represents pressing enter/return key then your code will work fine (well, maybe beside the fact that `while(scanner.hasNextLine())` will not return `false` untill `System.in` will be closed which is why we rather loop for N values or until some exit condition is met like when user will write `EXIT`).

Comment: @Pshemo The block of commands will always end with Q, and that's when the Q case will close the scanner and exit the program. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, you will need to utilize these sub-strings at some point outside of your **while** loop so it would actually be better to split the line based on the same delimiter and have each substring as a element within a String Array This way you don't need to utilize Scanner and a **while** loop for this at all, for example:

```
String input = "first line \n second line \n third line"; // Read in data file line...
String[] stuffArray = input.split("\\s+?\n\\s+?");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stuffArray));
System.out.println();
System.out.println("     OR in other words");
System.out.println();
for(String str : stuffArray) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

If you want to do this using System.in:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter text:");
String stuff = sc.nextLine();
String[] subArray = stuff.trim().split("(\\s+)?(\\\\n)(\\s+)?");
System.out.println();
    
// Display substrings...
for (String strg : subArray) {
    System.out.println(strg);
}
```

Comment: Based fact that "Output: `first \n second \n third" we can assume that `\n` is not line-separator but serie of two characters: ``\`` and `n` (otherwise output wouldn't contain `\n` as text) so making delimiter `\n` will not affect it. So it is like scanning string `"first line \\nsecond line \\nthird line"`.

Comment: I haven't used delimiter before, hmm interesting! I'm pretty new to Java so I'm still trying to figure my way through it, thank for educating me!

Comment: @Pshemo so does this not work with `Scanner(System.in)`?

Comment: @CaoTheNoob `nextLine()` doesn't take *delimiter* into account so even if you set it to `sc.useDelimiter("elephant");` this example will give you same results. Delimiter is important for rest of methods which work with tokens like `next()` `nextInt()` etc.